# Symfony getters and setters generation - how to ignore a property

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Using Symfony2.0, I know well how to use the command `doctrine:generate:entities` to generate getters and setters.

The question: is there any annotation, parameter or so to make the command ignore some property which I don't need the methods for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. [The generator](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#generating-getters-and-setters) is meant to be used to start quickly — not to do your coding job. So, generate an entity and then remove whatever you don't need.

Comment: Ok, thank you! I think is a nonsense work to do as it always generates all the entities getters and setters and, therefor, I'll have to delete the code I don't want every time I execute the command. Sort of weak, isn't it?

Comment: I've never used a Symfony2 or Doctrine2 code generator in 1.5 years of developing with them, so the life without them is definitely possible. ;)

Comment: LOL, Thanks... good to know. I used it as the "oracle" ;). Not any more :)

Comment: I not agree with that opinion. Generator userful not only at the beginning of entity coding (also note that it makes backuped files witch means that it is expected use case).